# How to check device compatibility for finger print authentication in android API lower than 23

Tags: android

I am working with finger print authentication using android 5.0 api. My requirement is, if current device is supports finger print authentication, then I will go through finger print authentication else will use normal way, but need to check every device of api 18 and above if they have finger print scanner or not.

So, any one can tell me, how to check device compatibility for finger print authentication in android.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you going to use the official API (`FingerprintManager`)? If so, that API was added in API level 23. If you don't want to have to deal with checking for API level 23 you can use `FingerprintManagerCompat`. Both of these have an `isHardwareDetected` method.

Comment: FingerprintManagerCompat is having a parser problem, and also its constustor is private. 
Can you tell me how to initialize FingerprintManagerCompat.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Use the `from` method, which is listed in the documentation.

Comment: Thanx its works :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Build.VERSION.SDK_INT](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION.html#SDK_INT)

```
Log.i("TEST", "API Level is: " + Build.VERSION.SDK_INT);
```

So:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 18) {
    // do the job.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
FingerprintManager fingerprintManager = (FingerprintManager)getSystemService(FINGERPRINT_SERVICE);


if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2){
          if(!fingerprintManager.isHardwareDetected()){
               //your device doesn't have fingerprint Sensor
          }else{
            // do your code..
          }
    }
```